# How Android launcher works?

Tags: android, android-launcher

hello everyone I want to know what happens when we click on app icon of any particular app.How OS launch that app?.Please describe it.

Comment: The home screen calls `startActivity()` on an explicit `Intent` identifying the activity that the user selected.

Comment: @CommonsWare which home screen...

Comment: Any app, such as a home screen/launcher, that wants to start an activity, will call `startActivity()` or related methods (e.g., `startActivityForResult()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on app icon android package manager will check manifest file and find launcher activity which has intent filter for that and will search for action as Main and category as default. When it find that detail it will launch that main activity.

Comment: thanks it is the answer of my question.

Comment: welcome mate , glad i could help you :)